# Excel - How can I detect the X lowest consecutive values within a column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I was hoping that someone might help me with a problem I'm trying to sort out.  Does anyone know a formula that could detect the 10 lowest consecutive readings within a single column.

Thank you for any assistance.

SFinch

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What have you tried?

Comment: Also, I think the meaning of your question isn't obvious. Please give an example or two of what you do and do not mean by "the 10 lowest consecutive readings".

Answer (score 0):

**First you need to sort:**

**1.** Select a column of numeric data in a range of cells, or make sure
    that the active cell is in a table column containing numeric data.

**2.** On the Data tab, in the Sort & Filter group, do
    the following:

- [click on this button](https://support.content.office.net/en-US/media/82e575eb-0061-4c0b-8699-fb95a5b1c2e8.gif) to sort Smallest to Largest.

**Second you extract:**

[You can follow the procedure outlined here.](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1656-excel-extract-first-character.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the rank function in a conditional format eg

=RANK(E4,E$4:E$20,1)<11

[image]

which would colour the lowest 10 items and colour them